# Intellij dependency viewer and package cyclic dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies

All my programming life I have been thinking that the cyclic dependency is the following:
**GIVEN**

- package1
- package2

  - subpackage2
- package3

**IF**

1. Class from package1 references class from package2
2. Class from package2 references class from package3
3. Class from package3 references class from package1

**THEN**
Project contains cyclic dependency package1 > package2 > package3 > package1.

This was a pretty huge surprise when Intellij's dependency viewer told me, that:

**IF**

1. Class from package1 references class from package2
2. Class from subpackage2 references class from package3
3. Class from package3 references class from package1

**THEN**
Project contains cyclic dependency package1 > package2 > package3 > package1.

Could anybody, please, explain me what is the strict definition for cyclic dependency and why does Intellij show such weird results? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to say that your first example would *not* qualify as a cyclic dependency in IntelliJ's view? Or are you surprised that the 2nd example does?

Comment: @kaqqao Second one. I'm surprised that Intellij treats second example a cyclic dependency.

Comment: Well, the dependencies are transitive, so by virtue of depending on subpackage2 which in turn depends on package3, package2 itself depends on package3, thus forming the exact same graph as example 1. I'm more surprised other tools *don't* see it as a circle. Why do you see these examples as fundamentally different?

Comment: @  kaqqao : that should be the answer. Question is vague, one cannot go beyond your assertion.

Comment: @Jayan Not sure why this seems vague to you. It is clear that there is misconception between tools checking cyclic dependency. Their results are just not the same.

Comment: @kaqqao, well, that's frustrating. If the second example _is_ correct, than I don't understand why other tools don't show dependencies intllij shows. E.g. findbugs.

Comment: IMHO, IntelliJ detection is better.  Why other tools give different result can be explained by them. Do you have a sample project that we can run against other tools you mentioned? Gradle/maven build will do.

Comment: @Jayan, will prepare one and share it, thanks.

Comment: It won't matter if your class is in a sub package. It's not really a question of packages. It's a question of dependencies between libraries. You should not have cyclic dependency in any sense between discrete libraries of code, or you have failed in your design.

Comment: @kaqqao, I updated jdepend to the last version in my eclipse and it showed these dependencies as well. Was unable to run FindBugs, but pretty sure it will show the same results. Please, post one of your comments as an answer to make me able to award the bounty. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @mr.nothing Cool to hear the mystery is resolved :) Posted the original comment as answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dependencies are transitive, so by virtue of depending on subpackage2 which in turn depends on package3, package2 itself depends on package3, thus forming the exact same graph as example 1. I'm more surprised other tools *don't* see it as a circle, as IntelliJ is correct here.

Comment: The actual problem was actually in our internal tool which shows only direct cycles and skips transitive ones. So I was really surprised when old jdepend and our internal tool had same results. Thanks for pointing helping out!